# C# MciSendString Recording, Works in debug, not deployed

Tags: c#, winmm, mci

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction with this. This code works perfectly when I'm debugging within Visual Studio Express 2010, but give me the mci error 263 - "The specified device is not open nor recognised by mci" when built and deployed.

I've tried tinkering with build settings and what not, but no joy. Surely this must be a config issue rather than the code?

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

----- Code Follows ----

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString,               int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern bool mciGetErrorString(int fdwError, StringBuilder lpszErrorText, int cchErrorText);

///Inside a button function
mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);

//Inside another button function
int i = mciSendString(@"save recsound C:/test22/sound", outs, 0, 0);
MessageBox.Show(""+i);

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(128);
bool returnValue = mciGetErrorString(i, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
string err = buffer.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(buffer.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I got your code to work by actually specifying a file to save it as...

```
string outs = "";
//Inside another button function
int i = mciSendString(@"save recsound C:/test.wav", ref outs, 0, 0);
```

I also changed the out parameter to a ref though I doubt that had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

What type of file are you trying to play? And where is it deployed? I recently came upon the same issue; I cannot play .mp3s or .wmas on one of my test machines (I get the same error: `263`). I installed Windows Media Player and they worked, so this leads me to believe that a codec is missing. Now I just have to figure out what codec(s) it was.